# Loop to select pairwise series

Tags: r, iteration

I have a `data.frame` in R with 40 series and I want to select pairwise series to apply a function, (ie serie 1 and serie 21, serie 2 and serie 22) . However I'm getting error with the following code:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(Date)) {
    pairwise <-Date[, c(i,i+20)]
}
```

I want to use `pairwise` in other function.

Could someone please help me?

Thank in advance

Comment: what "other function" do you want to use? I.e. what do you want to do with the pairwise series. There seems little point in copying / duplicating data in a loop to use in some other function when indexing will suffice. But if you tell us the function you want to use, and what the real problem is, perhaps we can provide more efficient solutions? Edit your Question to provide more info, or add a comment here.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. I have a dataframe with unemployment an productivity rates for 20 countries, so I have 40 series in my dataframe. I have to select de pairwise because I want to use "ca.jo" function from "urca" package, which allows me study cointegration relationship between the "pairwise" series. If I do it manually it takes a long time so I wanted to apply a loop to allow me to implement it at once.
for(i in 1:ncol(Date)) {
    pairwise <-Date[, c(i,i+20)]
    rt <- ca.jo(pairwise, K=2, season=spec="longrun")
    print(summary(rt))
}
Thank you very much

Comment: You don't need `pairwise`, just index directly in `ca.jo`: `rt <- ca.jo(Date[, c(i,i+20)], K=2, season=spec="longrun")`

Comment: Hi, when I run the code: for(i in 1:ncol(Date)) {
   rt <- ca.jo(Date[, c(i,i+20)], K=2, season=spec="longrun")
print(summary(rt))} I get this error message: "subscript out of bounds" Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

It is because you are requesting columns higher than 40 when `i` > 20. See this example:

```
set.seed(1)
DF <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(40*100), ncol = 40))

## simple function to apply/use
foo <- function(x1, x2) return(x1 - x2)

## something to hold results
res <- matrix(ncol = ncol(DF), nrow = nrow(DF))

## loop - oops error
for(i in seq_len(ncol(DF))) {
    res[,i] <- foo(DF[,i], DF[,i+20])
}
```

You get this error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(DF, , i + 20) : undefined columns selected
```

That is because `i` takes values 1, ..., 40. As soon as i >= 21, (i + 20) > 40 and you only have 40 columns of data. A simple modification is to loop only over the first 20 columns:

```
## something to hold results
res <- matrix(ncol = ncol(DF) / 2, nrow = nrow(DF))
for(i in seq_len(ncol(DF)/2)) {
    res[,i] <- foo(DF[,i], DF[,i+20])
}
```

if all you want is col 1 and col 21, col 2 and col 22 etc. If you want all pairwise comparisons then you need to try something different, as a single loop won't work.

(Before someone pulls me up for woefully inefficient use of a loop, that example was just that, an example with no imagination applied to the function `foo()`. In this case, `DF[, 1:20] - DF[, 21:40]` will give the same result as in `res`.)